# making an array of a textfile

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

im getting problems at ln 40 saying katterna cannot be resolved to a variable. Not sure whats wrong. Im pretty new with using a array when reading every row in the textfile indivudualy.

Thanks!

MAIN:

```
package inlammningsuppgifterskolan;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Katt2 {
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException{

    String namn;
    String farg;
    int ar;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("katter.txt"));

    sc.useDelimiter("#");

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        sc.nextLine();
        i++;
    }

    Katt3 [] katterna = new Katt3[i];

    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("katter.txt"));

    while(sc2.hasNextLine()){
        namn = sc.next();
        farg = sc.next();
        ar = sc.nextInt();
    }

    while(j<i){
        katterna[j] = new Katt3(namn, farg, ar);
        j++;
    }
    sc.close();

    Katterna[0].setAr(125);
    System.out.println(katterna[0].getAr());

    System.out.println(katterna[0]);
    System.out.println(katterna[1]);
    System.out.println(katterna[2]);
}
```

}

CLASS:

```
package inlammningsuppgifterskolan;

public class Katt3 {

private String namn, farg; //fname blabla LÄR DIG DET OCKSÅ
private int ar; //fname blabla LÄR DIG DET OCKSÅ

public Katt3(String namn, String farg, int ar){ 
    this.namn=namn;
    this.farg=farg;
    this.ar=ar;
    //fname blabla LÄR DIG DET OCKSÅ
}

public void setAr(int ar){
    this.ar = ar;
    //fname blabla LÄR DIG DET OCKSÅ
}
public int getAr(){
    return ar;
    //fname blabla LÄR DIG DET OCKSÅ
}
public String toString(){
    //NÄR STRING FORMAT? vrf ej bara return?
    //String format endast vid %-15s blabla right..?
    //return String.format("%-15s, %-12s, %3d", namn, farg, ar);
    return "namn " + namn + " farg " + farg + " ar " + ar;
}
}
```

Comment: java (variable) names are case sensitive.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Katterna[0].setAr(125);` Which `setAr()` method are you trying to call with the array?

Answer (score 1):

At line 40,(Katterna[0]) the 'K' is capital. The variable name is katterna.

Comment: It is discouraged to answer typo questions. They don't add any value to the site. You could've written a comment and flagged as off-topic.